# Visual Studio 2013, unable to create Win32 Console Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, ide

I tried repairing the installation and reinstalling everything from scratch but nothing seems to fix this problem. This problem also exists when I try to create a Win32 Application in Visual C++ as well as Visual Studio 2013.

Clicking finish and cancel seem to do nothing while the only button that works is the red X on the top right hand corner.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrwbU.png

I have heard good things about this IDE but I can't seem to create a new project. Please help!

Comment: "Have you tried to turn it off and on again ?" #kidding

Comment: Did you select "empty" project after clicking on next and before clicking on finish? After this, you can use "add existing item" to add your source file(s).

Comment: That wizard-step is implemented in JScript, you need to configure your machine to allow it to execute.  Users that are this paranoia usually also have a nasty kind of anti-malware installed, that causes plenty of trouble as well when VS makes executable files appear from nowhere.

Comment: @rcgldr I tried creating an empty project and adding a C++ class to it and encountered the same problem (dialogue with no current project settings, finish/cancel button completely screwed). I tried reinstalling from scratch already the third time, with the same error/bug.

Comment: @HansPassant Uninstalled my Norton that came with my copy of windows but I still have CCleaner, might CCleaner be the problem?